# 3D parametric plot with three parameters using any language or software

Tags: plot, parameters, 3d, wolfram-mathematica, 4d

I'm looking for a possibility to plot 3D objects using vectors with three parameters using any language or software (I prefer Mathematica but obviously it's very complicated there). They are of the form

```
{x,y,z} = {f[u,v,w], g[u,v,w], h[u,v,w]}
```

and I'd like to vary *u*, *v* and *w* to plot the surface traced out by the equation and to determine its colour at each point. Usual 3D plots are only able to deal with two parameters. Plots of discrete points are not helpful here. Is there a way to do it?

The three parameters arise from a projection of a 4D-object onto the 3D plane.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot3D.html

Comment: this needs more specificity. Presumably your parameters span some geometric volume in `u,v,w` space, so you likely want to map the surface of that volume to a surface in `x,y,z` space. (effectively reducing it to a 2 parameter problem, so you can use `ParametricPlot3D` etc )  That assumes some niceness conditions on `f,g,h` of course..

Comment: `f,g,h` are periodic in `u,v,w`, but they may take on different forms and can be quite sophisticated. If `u,v,w` are varied, a closed volume is traced out in `x,y,z` space. Finding a parametric equation for the boundary would be ideal and could be found in principle, but I have no idea how to do it analytically.